# Missing Modules message while compiling a program using py2exe

Tags: py2exe

I am attempting to take a program I created and turn it into an executable.  It is not a fancy program at all and I believe I should be able to bundle all the dependencies into the executable to make distribution easier.  The executable is produced, but when I try to run it I get the message

```
C:\Users\chadd\OneDrive\Desktop\parser>Parser_002.exe
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Users\chadd\OneDrive\Desktop\parser\Parser_002.exe'
  isolated = 1
  environment = 0
  user site = 0
  import site = 0
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\chadd\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\parser\\Parser_002.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\chadd\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\parser\\Parser_002.exe'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\chadd\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\parser\\library.zip',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000000e0 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

Here is the message I receive in the command prompt window when executing the compile:

```
C:\Users\chadd\OneDrive\Desktop\parser>python setup.py py2exe
C:\Users\chadd\OneDrive\Desktop\parser\setup.py:7: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
  from distutils.core import setup
running py2exe

  13 missing Modules
  ------------------
? __main__                            imported from bdb, pdb
? _frozen_importlib                   imported from importlib, importlib.abc, zipimport
? _frozen_importlib_external          imported from importlib, importlib._bootstrap, importlib.abc, zipimport
? _posixshmem                         imported from multiprocessing.resource_tracker, multiprocessing.shared_memory
? _winreg                             imported from platform
? asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy      imported from -
? dummy.Process                       imported from multiprocessing.pool
? java.lang                           imported from platform
? org.python.core                     imported from copy, pickle
? os.path                             imported from ctypes._aix, distutils.file_util, os, pkgutil, py_compile, sysconfig, tracemalloc, unittest, unittest.util
? pep517                              imported from importlib.metadata
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? resource                            imported from test.support
Building 'dist\Parser_002.exe'.
Building shared code archive 'dist\library.zip'.
```

Here is the setup.py script I am using:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
 
setup(console=['Parser_002.py'],options={"py2exe": {"unbuffered": True,"optimize": 2,"bundle_files": 0,"compressed": False,"includes": [],"excludes" : [],"packages": [],"dll_excludes": []}})
```

I have tried checking the python path to ensure that the path points to the directories where all the python libraries and modules are located. Everything seems correct there.

I have tried compiling the program without bundling and it will compile and properly execute as long as the executable is still in a directory with all the other ./dist files that get generated by py2exe

Comment: I can't promise, but the line "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'" tells me you had an issue with your original python installation, or don't have it configured correctly. You should try updating your python install, because encodings is part of the original python installation. From the error messages, it seems like this is the problem, maybe it's corrupted.